# Getting QWindow back into parent QWidget from the fullscreen

Tags: qt

I have an object that subclasses [QWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html). I add it into my `QMainWindow`'s layout by wrapping it into `QWidget` container like this:

```
  myWinContainer= QWidget::createWindowContainer(myWindow,this);
  vbox->addWidget(myWinContainer);
  myWinContainer->setFixedSize(640,360);
```

Then there is a fullscreen mode. I tried to set screen mode directly on `myWindow` (QWindow):

```
 myWindow->setParent(nullptr);
 myWindow->showFullScreen();
```

The windows goes full screen all right. But I can't get it back into its widget when exiting from the full screen.

```
 myWindow->setWindowState(Qt::WindowNoState);
 myWindow->setParent(p);//where p is cached pointer to parent: myWindow->parent()
 myWindow->showNormal();
```

The window stays detached from the main window.

Then I tried to do the full screen via myWindow's parent widget (`myWinContainer`). In this case, every time I am inserting `myWinContainer` back into its parent :

```
  vbox->insertWidget(0,myWinContainer);
```

layout object, it crashes with some deep internal error.

Comment: Don't use QWindow but QWidget then. I did reparenting of widgets and they seem to work.

Comment: I must use Qwindow.  I have no problem with a typical QWidget

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to recreate the window container:

```
class Foo : public QWidget {
  QWidget * m_container = {};
  QWindow m_window;
  QVBoxLayout m_vBox;
  // ...
};

void Foo::contain() {
  // invoke each time the window is shown not-full-scale
  delete m_container; // removes from the layout, too
  m_container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(&m_window, this);
  m_container->setFixedSize(640,360);
  m_vBox->addWidget(myWinContainer);
}
```

Comment: When I delete the container, the QWindow it wraps gets destroyed as well. That's not what I want.I have no problem with recreating the QWidget as it is just a container, but the QWindow has alot of stuff going on in runtime, so I am trying to find a solution which doesn't require killing of the QWindow.